# The Folium library can't generate maps

Tags: html, leaflet, folium

Since yesterday afternoon, I have not succeeded in using Folium to generate maps, even the most basic display function can not be completed, the network connection is normal, it is likely that there is a problem with the call of js.

I tried switching the network environment and trying to change computers, but it didn't work.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
leaflet.awesome-markers.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined
at leaflet.awesome-markers.js:17
at leaflet.awesome-markers.js:122
leaflet.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
map.html:39 Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined
at map.html:39

#This is the code for the most basic function I've tried.

import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[29.488869,106.571034],
              zoom_start=16,
              control_scale=True,
              width='50%')

m.save('map.html')
```

I hope to generate map pages

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue. it worked fine on my system. there must be some set up problem in yours

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any problem in your jupyter notebook/Python IDLE. Check with your browser. If you’ve determined that the ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID is caused by an issue on your computer, try these steps to resolve it:

- First things first, check the Date and Time set on your computer, if
  these are wrong it probably explains how you got the
  ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID error.
- Sometimes fixing this error is as simple as shutting down your
  browser and then restarting it. Other times a system reboot may work.
  However, there are a couple of instances where you’ll need to do a
  little more work to set things straight.
- Check your connection, if you’re connected to public WiFi or some
  other public network there’s a chance that your browser is right and
  you don’t actually have a secure connection. If that’s the case, stop
  browsing and resume when you’re on a more secure setup.
- Scan your computer with a trusted antivirus software, you may have
  malware of some sort that is causing the issue. Unfortunately we
  can’t provide you with info on how to fix every last piece of
  malware, but if your antivirus can’t, someone on the internet
  probably knows.
- Disable any third-party plugins you have running on Chrome. Sometimes
  these can cause unwanted problems.
- Clear your browser cache on Chrome. Click the menu icon, open History
  and select “clear browsing data.”
- Delete and then re-install Chrome. Sometimes this helps.
- There are a few other crazy fixes like bringing down your firewall or
  modifying network settings. However I would not suggest this one since your PC then become susceptible to virus.